# Is there a known security risk with Firebase when allowing reads from a collection only if a UID exists in a deeper sub-collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a structure like this:

```
groups/{groupID}/groupInfo
groups/{groupID}/groupMembers
```

This is for a group chat. In this setup, I need to store general information about the group (groupInfo) and who is in it (groupMembers). If I use something like what I have below to only allow reads on the groupInfo collection if the UID exists in groupMembers, is there any risk to it? To me, the safest bet seems to be to allow reads of collections deeper down if the rule passes successfully up top. In the example case below, it would be a lateral check. Are there any inherent risks with Firebase in evaluating rules laterally?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow reading groupInfo collection if user's UID is in groupMembers collection
    match /groups/{groupID}/groupInfo/{document=**} {
      allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupID)/groupMembers/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
    
    // Allow reading groupMembers collection
    match /groups/{groupID}/groupMembers/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "the norm" is entirely subjective and a matter of opinion, which is off topic for Stack Overflow.  Either you decide to allow it or you don't.  If you need help deciding, I suggest posting a forum that allows for questions seeking opionions, such as Reddit.

Comment: Your example at the top of this post is borderline nonsense. If you're going to say "This is what my structure looks like" then use the standard descriptive format for documents and collections, e.g., `/collection/{documentId}/subCollection/{subDocumentId}`, not whatever that code block at the top is.